# Function stops working on HTML but works fine on console

Tags: javascript, html, function, console

The function below work fine on console, but stops working on the html page. What am I doing wrong?

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var newWin = window.open("http://www.google.com");
newWin.onload = function(){
newWin.document.body.style.transform = "scale(2)";
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly are you putting in the console

Comment: `function myFunction() {
var newWin = window.open("http://www.google.com");
newWin.onload = function(){
newWin.document.body.style.transform = "scale(2)";
}

myFuntion();`

This @LukaKostic

Comment: Try putting the script tag above the <button> tags

Comment: Button stops working when I do that since its part of the script @LukaKostic

Comment: What actually did not work... Exact point??

Comment: On the original format it actually opens the new page but does nothing after that. @LukaKostic

Comment: On the original code it actually opens the new page but does nothing after that. @BiploveLamichhane

Comment: My guess is security. You dont want any old page opening eg your facebook and executing actions thru javascript. So your '.onload' doesnt even get called. Executing from console probably is different there and allows more since its the actual user doing it.

Comment: otherwise imagine window.open('paypal.com') and js code to click the transfer button and enter data... Pretty sure when you open the new window, you dont have any control over it from the current page. Not sure how it works at all from console.

Comment: @LukaKostic makes sense. Would you have any tips on how to scale up a page after it is loaded? That's basically what I'm trying to accomplish. I understant zooming is a user choice, but there's a legit reason in this case. Thanks!

Comment: I dont know any way of it working on multiple domains (and domains you dont own such as google.com) unless you use browser extensions. Greasemonkey or Tampermonkey extensions are great since you can put your own js code and they have many great functionalities

Comment: I'll look into it. Thank you very much! @LukaKostic